# Drag and Drop to QPlainTextBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qplaintextedit

I'm trying to develop an ide with Pyqt5. What I want is to drag the contents of the list into the TextBox. The list elements should work like a button. For example, for "Sum", printf (a + b); should.

But it doesn't let me drop the List element into the textBox.

How can I do this?

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1055, 814)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.plainTextEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferDefault)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setFont(font)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_3")
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setAcceptDrops(True)




        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit_3)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_6)
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.line_3)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(754, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setWhatsThis("")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.East)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.tab)
        self.tabWidget_2.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tabWidget_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tabWidget_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget_2.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabWidget_2.setObjectName("tabWidget_2")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_6.setObjectName("gridLayout_6")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkableButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.checkableButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.checkableButton.setChecked(True)
        self.checkableButton.setObjectName("checkableButton")
        self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.checkableButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(132, 50))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1055, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMenu.setObjectName("menuMenu")
        self.menuSubmenu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuMenu)
        self.menuSubmenu_2.setObjectName("menuSubmenu_2")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
        self.dockWidget1 = QtWidgets.QDockWidget(MainWindow)
        self.dockWidget1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 284))
        self.dockWidget1.setObjectName("dockWidget1")
        self.dockWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents.setObjectName("dockWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.dockWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_10.setObjectName("verticalLayout_10")
        self.toolBox = QtWidgets.QToolBox(self.dockWidgetContents)
        self.toolBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.toolBox.setObjectName("toolBox")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 132, 211))
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.page)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.page)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.listWidget.setDragEnabled(True)

        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.toolBox.addItem(self.page, "")
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 132, 211))
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.listWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.page_2)
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.listWidget_2)
        self.verticalWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.page_2)
        self.verticalWidget.setObjectName("verticalWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.verticalWidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.toolBox.addItem(self.page_2, "")
        self.page_7 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 132, 211))
        self.page_7.setObjectName("page_7")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_7)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.verticalWidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.page_7)
        self.verticalWidget1.setObjectName("verticalWidget1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalWidget1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.listWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.verticalWidget1)
        self.listWidget_3.setObjectName("listWidget_3")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_3.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_3.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_3.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_3.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget_3.addItem(item)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.listWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.verticalWidget1, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.toolBox.addItem(self.page_7, "")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.toolBox)
        self.dockWidget1.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents)
        MainWindow.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), self.dockWidget1)
        self.dockWidget2 = QtWidgets.QDockWidget(MainWindow)
        self.dockWidget2.setObjectName("dockWidget2")
        self.dockWidgetContents_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("dockWidgetContents_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.toolBox_2 = QtWidgets.QToolBox(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        self.toolBox_2.setObjectName("toolBox_2")
        self.page_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 132, 347))
        self.page_5.setObjectName("page_5")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_5)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.verticalWidget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.page_5)
        self.verticalWidget2.setObjectName("verticalWidget2")
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName("verticalLayout_9")
        self.pushButton_24 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.pushButton_24.setObjectName("pushButton_24")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_24)
        self.pushButton_25 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.pushButton_25.setObjectName("pushButton_25")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_25)
        self.pushButton_29 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.pushButton_29.setObjectName("pushButton_29")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_29)
        self.pushButton_30 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.pushButton_30.setObjectName("pushButton_30")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_30)
        self.pushButton_28 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.pushButton_28.setObjectName("pushButton_28")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_28)
        self.pushButton_27 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.pushButton_27.setObjectName("pushButton_27")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_27)
        self.pushButton_26 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.pushButton_26.setObjectName("pushButton_26")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_26)
        self.pushButton_23 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalWidget2)
        self.pushButton_23.setObjectName("pushButton_23")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_23)
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.verticalWidget2, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.toolBox_2.addItem(self.page_5, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.toolBox_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.dockWidget2.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        MainWindow.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), self.dockWidget2)
        self.toolBar_2 = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar_2.setObjectName("toolBar_2")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar_2)
        self.actionAction = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAction.setObjectName("actionAction")
        self.actionSub_menu = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSub_menu.setObjectName("actionSub_menu")
        self.actionAction_C = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAction_C.setObjectName("actionAction_C")
        self.dockWidget1.raise_()
        self.menuSubmenu_2.addAction(self.actionSub_menu)
        self.menuSubmenu_2.addAction(self.actionAction_C)
        self.menuMenu.addAction(self.actionAction)
        self.menuMenu.addAction(self.menuSubmenu_2.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu.menuAction())
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionAction)
        self.toolBar.addSeparator()
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionSub_menu)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabWidget_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.toolBox.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.toolBox_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.pushButton, self.checkableButton)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.checkableButton, self.pushButton_5)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.pushButton_5, self.tabWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setPlainText(_translate("MainWindow", "#include <stdlib.h>\n"
        "\n"
        "main(){\n"
        "    printf ( Hello Wolrd!\");\n"
        "    return 0;\n"
        "}"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Compile"))
        self.checkableButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Compile and Run"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Değişken Yarat"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.menuMenu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "&Menu"))
        self.menuSubmenu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "&Submenu 2"))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
        self.dockWidget1.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Yapılar"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Topla"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Çıkar"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Çarp"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Böl"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Üst Al"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Kök Al"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Mod Al"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.toolBox.setItemText(self.toolBox.indexOf(self.page), _translate("MainWindow", "İşlemler"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget_2.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget_2.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "For"))
        item = self.listWidget_2.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "While"))
        item = self.listWidget_2.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "If"))
        item = self.listWidget_2.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Switch / Case"))
        self.listWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.toolBox.setItemText(self.toolBox.indexOf(self.page_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Döngüler"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget_3.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget_3.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget_3.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Değer Al"))
        item = self.listWidget_3.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Atama Yap"))
        item = self.listWidget_3.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Çıktı Yaz"))
        item = self.listWidget_3.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Kes"))
        item = self.listWidget_3.item(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Devam Et"))
        self.listWidget_3.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.toolBox.setItemText(self.toolBox.indexOf(self.page_7), _translate("MainWindow", "Deyimler"))
        self.dockWidget2.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Algoritmalar"))
        self.pushButton_24.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Quick Sort"))
        self.pushButton_25.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Merge Sort"))
        self.pushButton_29.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Radix Sort"))
        self.pushButton_30.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Insertion Sort"))
        self.pushButton_28.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Bubble Sort"))
        self.pushButton_27.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Counting Sort"))
        self.pushButton_26.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Heap Sort"))
        self.pushButton_23.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Selection Sort"))
        self.toolBox_2.setItemText(self.toolBox_2.indexOf(self.page_5), _translate("MainWindow", "Sıralama Algoritması"))
        self.toolBar_2.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar_2"))
        self.actionAction.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "&Action"))
        self.actionSub_menu.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "&Action B"))
        self.actionSub_menu.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "submenu"))
        self.actionAction_C.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action &C"))

import style_Dark_rc
import style_black_rc

import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

QPlainTextEdit only supports plain text such as drag-and-drop information but in the case of QListWidget it sends information with another mimeType so it fails.

**Solution:**

There are 2 alternatives: Add the functionality of accepting data with another mimeType to QPlaintTextedit, or have the information source (in this case the QListWidget) send the information as plain text. In this case I will implement the latter since it is the simplest solution.

When information is sent from one element to another through drag-and-drop, a QMimeData is used that is sent through the event sent by the source and the event received by the receiver, in the case of QListWidget it has the method [`mimeData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#mimeData) which converts items to QMimeData so that method can be overridden by adding plain text. Then we only import it in the script:

```
# ...

class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def mimeData(self, items):
        md = super().mimeData(items)
        text = "".join([it.text() for it in items])
        md.setText(text)
        return md


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # ...
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        # self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.page)
        self.listWidget = ListWidget(self.page)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. My goal is to print a text already. But let me show you a popup after you let me get the value of a and b here. I wanted him to say ok. I need to edit Class for this, right? Can I show a popup when dropping in class?

Comment: @OnurhanErkoç That is another question and therefore I will not answer it here since this section is exclusive to answer questions about my answer. If you have other problems then write a new question showing what you have tried